# Use either routerLink or href based on value whether it is internal or external

Tags: html, angular, angular-router, routerlink

I want in my anchor elements to use either [routerLink] if the provided url is external or [href] whether it's internal url. The problem is i don't know what url it will be, because it comes from backend.

I tried to use directive and replace attribute like below:

```
this.el.nativeElement.setAttribute('routerLink', this.routerOrHref);
```

or

```
this.el.nativeElement.setAttribute('href', this.routerOrHref);
```

but using this solution makes `routerLink` useless, becuase it does not generate `href`.

Is there any solution to apply it for the code?

```
<a
  data-cy="footer-links"
  (click)="onNavigate(item)"
  [routerLink or href here based on if url is external or internal] = [item.url]
>
```

I actually do not want to put 2 anchor tags and determine which should be displayed like this:

```
<a *ngIf="extern" [routerLink]="link"></a>
<a *ngIf="!extern" [href]="link"></a>
```

It's important in terms of SEO for me to have valid href. And the requirement is to use Angular RouterLink in that case, when it is external link.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to use `*ngIf` you can do this:

```
<a
  data-cy="footer-links"
  (click)="onNavigate(item)"
>
```

and `.ts` file:

```
onNavigate(item) {
    this.extern ? this.router.navigate([`${externalUrl}`]) :
     window.location.href = internalUrl
    // You can also use Location class of Angular
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not actually what I was looking for. My focus is to provide valid href because of SEO. Navigation is already done and I am not sure if i can modify it. My requirement is to use routerLink when the link is external, and href when it's internal. I am not quite sure if it is possible to achieve that's why I'm asking.

Comment: in that case I would recommend building a component that injects the platform, in which you could then do a ngIf else, to either render with href or routerlink